# implicit declaration error in compiler output with gcc -Wall

Tags: c, unix, compiler-errors

I keep getting an error with my function and i have checked other answers for help and can't find any.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

double celsius_at_depth(double celtemp);
double fahrenhiet(double fahrtemp);

int main(void)
{
  double depth;
  double celsius;
  double fahre;

  printf("Enter the depth in kilometers inside the earth >    \n");
  scanf("%lf",&depth);

  celsius = celsius_at_depth(depth);
  fahre = fahrenheit(celsius);

  printf("At depth of %.1lf km inside the earth, the temperature is:\n\n",depth);
  printf("   %.2lf degrees Celsius\n\n",celsius);
  printf("   %.2lf degrees Fahrenheit\n\n",fahre);

  return(0);
}

double celcius_at_depth(double celtemp)

{
  return(10*celtemp+32);
}

double fahrenheit(double fahrtemp)

{
  return(1.8*fahrtemp+32);
}
```

and the error message is

```
Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
celsius_at_depth                    /var/tmp//ccYYWsC0.o
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors. No output written to a.out
```

I need to have this functions output to just tell me the depth again, the temp in fahrenhiet and the temp in celsius.  Please help, i have been stuck forever

Comment: Check your spelling.

Comment: You have declared the function to be `fahrenhiet` while you are calling `farenhiet` -- a missing `h`.

Comment: That's not how you spell "Fahrenheit" in any case. "Fahrenheit" is the name of a German physicist, and it doesn't follow the `i` before `e` rule in English.

Answer (score 2):

You declare:

```
double celsius_at_depth(double celtemp);
double fahrenhiet(double fahrtemp);
```

but you define:

```
double celcius_at_depth(double celtemp) ...
double fahrenheit(double fahrtemp) ...
```

and invoke:

```
celsius = celsius_at_depth(depth);
fahre = fahrenheit(celsius);
```

celsius != celcius and fahrenhiet != fahrenheit

You probably also got a compilation warning about the implicit declaration of a function fahrenheit.